# pl/sql create a rowlevel trigger

Tags: plsql

Create a row level trigger “dep_check” that fires before insert operation associated with employees table. The trigger should check if the new Department_Number exist in Departments table. If the Department_Number does not exist in Department table, a new department record will be created (‘you can name it any name’) and the Department_Number should be the new value in the insert statement. print a message ‘Department # is created’  replace the # with the department_no. if the department exist already, the trigger should print ‘Employee record inserted’.

This is what i tried but it gives me error

```
enter code here


 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dep_check
BEFORE INSERT
ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

if new.department_number in departments THEN
dbms_output.put_line ('Employee record inserted.');

else 
insert into departments values (:new.department_number,:new.employee_id,
         :new.Last_name, :new.first_name, :new.manager_id);
dbms_output.put_line ('department '|| old.department_number || 'is created. '||
'replace the ' || old.department ||' with the '|| new.department_number);
end if;
end;
```

Comment: You need to run a select query to check if exists. By the way, why are you storing employee's details in department table? Furthermore, displaying  from a trigger using `dbms_output` is not useful. It won't appear on screen in most cases.

Comment: Also, you need to ensure you're referring to the `new` and `old` records as bind variables in all places - i.e. `:new.<field name>` and `:old.<field name>` - note the presence of the `:`! You say "it gives me error"... what error? We aren't sitting behind you, so can't see your screen. Please edit your question to include the error message you're getting.